# Do all prior vestiges of VS need to be uninstalled before installing VS 2012 for Windows 8?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, windows-7, installation, visual-studio-express

Four hours on the appropriate msdn forum (Visual Studio Developer Center > Visual Studio vNext Forums >  Visual Studio Setup and Installation) and not a bite, so I'll try here:

I'm trying to install Visual Studio for Windows 8 on my laptop, on which I just installed the Windows 8 OS RC.

I already had Visual Studio 2012 Pro RC (for Windows 7) installed.

I tried to install VS for w8, but after 10-12 hours of installation (it seemed stuck on the "Blend" cycle), I canceled out and decided to uninstall both versions of VS 2012 (Pro for pre-W8 and Express for W8) before proceeding again with installation of VS Express 2012 for Windows 8.

Control Panel showed both versions of VS 2012 in my list of installed apps, although the W8 version hadn't finished installing (I did try to run it, to see if it would - it wouldn't).

Anyway, I uninstalled VS 2012 for W8 and am in the process of uninstalling VS 2012 Pro; is this to be expected (that the previous version first needs to be uninstalled before the new one will install)?

Note: Control Panel showed both versions of VS 2012 as having been installed on 7/23 (yesterday), whereas I really installed VS 2012 Pro a month or so ago...is this just because some of its components were updated, or...???

BTW, I also still have VS C# Express installed - do I need to uninstall that, too, before installing VS Express 2012 for W8?

Also, I downloaded the W8 OS, burned it to a DVD, created a (100 GB) partition so I could have W7 & W8 simultaneously, but my laptop did not offer a "boot from optical" option from the BIOS settings screen, so rather than installing W8 to my new partition, I had to install W8 from the DVD (no option was given to select a partition on which to install it), thus overwriting Windows 7 in order to install the Windows 8 OS.

Comment: Ohhh boy.  First of all, Windows 8 is available as a consumer preview, so it's a fair bet that big huge complicated programs like visual studio might not work exactly as expected.  I have not used either W8 or VS2012.

Comment: Since it's "Visual Studio for Windows 8" I would expect it to install and work on w8. True, you can't expect it all to be peaches and cream, goodness and light, &c., but it would be quite irregular if VS for W8 didn't install on W8, I reckon.

Comment: It's not the first time a microsoft product has had a bug.  :)  Are there any remnants of the old windows 7 installation causing trouble?

Comment: I don't know; there are no err msgs; it just acted like a CalTrans worker for several hours (no offense, Scott and Tobey - not you!).

Comment: So the sequence of events was 1) Win7 with VS 2012 Pro RC installed, 2) upgrade the OS to Win8 Release Preview 3) try to install VS Express for Win8, which fails.  Is that a correct, brief summary (it's not 100% clear to me what the start conditions were, or exactly which version(s) of VS are involved at each step).

Comment: Also, has there ever been a install of VS Dev 11 Beta (or developer Preview) on the machine?  My understanding is that installation of the VS 2012 RC (or forthcoming release) is not supported over top of the Dev Preview or Beta.  However, I don't have anything to refer to on that - it's just my recollection.

Comment: @Michael: your sequence is precisely correct. Also, C# Express 2010 was installed prior to VS 2012 Pro RC.

Comment: @Clay: What about VS Dev 11 Developer Preview or Beta?

Comment: @Michael: No, never installed those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the answer is to first uninstall previous versions of Visual Studio 2012; although I didn't uninstall C# Express 2010. It installed fine this time, so that's my best guess.

Either that or it was "just one of those things."